# How to write a more concise AngularJS form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a registration form with the help of AngularJS and using Bootstrap for the styling. I've got something working, but I'm pretty sure if I had more knowledge with Angular this could be greatly improved. So far I've got...

User-name field:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="validateCtrl">
<form name="myForm">

<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{true: 'has-success'}[myForm.email.$dirty]" ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[myForm.email.$invalid]">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-maxlength="254" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid"></span>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required!</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address!</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.maxlength">Email is too long!</span>
</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && !myForm.email.$invalid"></span>

</div>
```

Password Field:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{true: 'has-success'}[myForm.password.$dirty]" ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[myForm.password.$invalid]">

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="255" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid"></span>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required">Password is Required!</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.minlength">Password is too short!     </span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.maxlength">Password is too long!</span>
</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && !myForm.password.$invalid"></span>

</div>
```

Password Confirm:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{true: 'has-success'}[myForm.passwordrepeat.$dirty]" ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[myForm.passwordrepeat.$invalid]">

<label for="passwordrepeat">Confirm Password</label>
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="passwordrepeat" ng-model="passwordrepeat" placeholder="Confirm Password" required compare-to="password"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="myForm.passwordrepeat.$dirty && myForm.passwordrepeat.$invalid"></span>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.passwordrepeat.$dirty && myForm.passwordrepeat.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="myForm.passwordrepeat.$error.required">Second Password is Required!</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.passwordrepeat.$error">Passwords do not match!</span>
</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="myForm.passwordrepeat.$dirty && !myForm.passwordrepeat.$invalid"></span>

</div>
```

Submit Button:

```
<button 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  ng-disabled=
  "myForm.email.$invalid || 
   myForm.password.$invalid ||
   myForm.passwordrepeat.$invalid">
  Register
</button>

</form>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise on how I can make this code more concise? For starters, can this conditional ng-class expression be improved...

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{true: 'has-success'}[myForm.passwordrepeat.$dirty]" ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[myForm.passwordrepeat.$invalid]">
```

...this basically says, if the field is dirty, then if it's valid add the 'has-success' element else add 'has-error'. Is there a cleaner way of achieving this...

```
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required!</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address!</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.maxlength">Email is too long!</span>
```

Rather than listing every error? Finally, is there a preferred way of writing long expressions like this in the html template...

```
"myForm.email.$dirty && !myForm.email.$invalid"
```

I've tried to get my head around directives and I'm using one for the password confirm but I don't think they would make a big difference here (but I'm probably wrong).

Any help/advise on best practices greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at ng-message (if you are using angular 1.3+) for more concise control error feedback.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Found a neat tutorial on using ng-message, looks great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is sort of vague, however here are some great articles that will help in your quest for better Angular based forms :)

**Submitting AJAX Forms: The AngularJS Way**
https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way

**AngularJS Form Validation**
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

And since you're using Bootstrap and Angular:
**How to Correctly Use BootstrapJS and AngularJS Together**
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

```
<!-- FORM -->
<!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate> <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->

    <!-- NAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required>
    </div>

    <!-- USERNAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
    </div>

    <!-- EMAIL -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email">
    </div>

    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

---

```
// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
        }

    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks Leon. Those tutorials are pretty good, especially the form validation. Looks like there isn't a lot more I can do though to shorten my code though.

Comment: @user3042437 mind selecting my answer then? If those links helped.